# Change vertical alignment in word when copying a HTML table in

Tags: html, microsoft-word-2007

I have used Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to generate a nice HTML table. I've then copied it over into Word and it's gone pretty well. However I'm trying to vertically align the text. I can justify the text fine. But the table comes in with taller rows than the HTML but I can't seem to vertically align the text by

`highlighting -> table properties -> cell tab -> vertical align = center`

Nor can I adjust the height of the row using the same

`table properties -> row -> specify height`

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Check the paragraph format for the paragraphs in the table cells. Look for spacing before and after.

Comment: @DavidPostill When I click the paragraph button i see a small ¤ symbol. Not sure what that means in terms of trying to fix this though?

Comment: This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the paragraph mark in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last (or only) paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the cell.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh ok. Thank you. I can't seem to see any additional space before or after

Comment: To change the paragraph spacing see [Where is the Paragraph Spacing in Microsoft Word 2007, 2010 and 2013](http://www.addintools.com/documents/word/where-paragraph-spacing.html)